# Using stronger typed lists in derived objects than the parent has defined

Tags: c#, interface

Info:
IDogShelter and ICatShelter both inherit from IAnimalShelter.

Next, I have Cat and Dog classes which both implement and extend IAnimal.

```
IAnimalShelter has a List<IAnimal> called Animals.
ICatShelter has a List<Cat> called Animals.
IDogShelter has a List<Dog> called Animals.
```

Problem:
ICatShelter can't have a List called Animals because IAnimalShelter has it defined as a List of IAnimal.  VS says to use the "new" keyword.  And so I just take it away instead and don't have a List of IAnimal on the IAnimalShelter.

And so - I have a method called GetAnimalShelters() which returns List of IAnimalShelter.  I want then to be able to iterate through each IAnimal in the shelter, but can't because IAnimalShelter doesn't have a List of IAnimal.  This leaves me having to cast my results into ICatShelter or IDogShelter in order to iterate through, but I'd like to be able to successfully add List of IAnimal to the IAnimalShelter instead.  How can I do this?

For example:

```
public interface IAnimalShelter
{
    List<IAnimal> Animals { get; set; }
}

public interface ICatShelter
{
    List<Cat> Animals { get; set; }
}

public interface IDogShelter
{
    List<Dog> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
List<IAnimalShelter> shelters = GetShelters(search);  //Works
foreach (IAnimalShelter shelter in shelters)
{
    var x = shelter.Animals;  
}
```

So above, I want to just access the common parts of an animal, I want IAnimalShelter to have an Animals property, but for the derived shelter types to have more strongly typed Animals list.

Comment: I don't understand the need for the `List<Cat>` and `List<Dog>` within the ICatShelter and IDogShelter.  just when you initialize the `Animals` list just make it a `new List<Cat>` or `new List<Dog>`

Comment: My reasoning is that there are plenty of other places in the code which know they're dealing with Cats, say, and therefore like to be able to access Cat.Whiskers without casting the animals to a List<Cat>.

Comment: I went with this in the end chancea, because it turned out that the times I needed to access the special one or two properties outside of the interface was minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Your type `IAnimalShelter` is promising that its `Animals` property will yield an object whose `Add` method will accept a parameter of type `Animal`.  If `ICatShelter` derives from `IAnimalShelter`, it must also have an `Animals` property that yields an object whose `Add` method will accept a parameter of type `Animal`.

To make this model work, you should define `IShelter<out T> where T:Animal` which includes an `Animals` property of type `IReadOnlyList<T>`, and a `TryDonate(Animal it)` method which will request that the shelter take in a particular animal.  A `CatShelter : IShelter<Cat>` will be able to let client code receive a readable list of objects that are guaranteed to all be of type `Cat`, and clients may attempt to submit any kind of animal to it, though donations of types other than `Cat` will not get added to the list.

Comment: As of commenting I think this is the only answer that addresses the need to iterate through `IAnimals` given a reference to an `IAnimalShelter`, since a plain old `<T>` won't let you do variance. I think this answer would be improved by separating out the `TryDonate` method, since it's not even clear if the asker needs that functionality and it makes it look more complex. (Maybe `IEnumerable` could be mentioned alongside `IReadOnlyList` too.)

Answer (score 0):

This is called Generics. The following definitions should give you what you're looking for:

```
public interface IAnimal { }

public class Cat : IAnimal { }

public class Dog : IAnimal { }

public interface IAnimalShelter<T> where T : IAnimal
{
    List<T> Animals { get; set; } 
}

public interface ICatShelter : IAnimalShelter<Cat> { }

public interface IDogShelter : IAnimalShelter<Dog> { }
```

The `Animals` property of an `ICatShelter` will be `List<Cat>`.

Implement the class like this and the compiler is happy:

```
public class CatShelter : ICatShelter
{
    public List<Cat> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generics:

```
public interface IAnimalShelter<T> where T : IAnimal
{
    List<T> Animals { get; set; }
}

public class Cat: IAnimal
{
}

public interface ICatShelter : IAnimalShelter<Cat>
{
}

public class CatShelter: ICatShelter
{
    public List<Cat> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

Didnt test it but this should do the trick, if your ICatShelter doesnt add anything to IAnimalShelter you can even drop it and derive CatShelter directly from IAnimalShelter